# Сделать заглавным первый символ в каждом слове

Tags: java, строки

Я получаю `String` введенный с клавиатуры, он может содержать несколько слов и разное кол-во пробелов между ними. Мне нужно вернуть ту же строку только каждое слово с большой буквы. Кол-во пробелов и не литералов между словами должно остаться тоже. Я почитал про `substring`, я так понял мне надо организовать красивый регекс?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/how-to-capitalize-the-first-character-of-each-word-in-a-string И там целая куча решений, прям на Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно также сделать решение "в лоб" с использованием `substring`:

```
String s1 = "i want  to   make upper case", s2 = "";
s2 = s2 + s1.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(); //первый символ делаем заглавным
for (int i = 1; i < s1.length(); i++) {
    // смотрим, был ли слева пробел:
    if (" ".equals(s1.substring(i-1, i)))
        s2 = s2 + s1.substring(i, i+1).toUpperCase();
    else
        s2 = s2 + s1.substring(i, i+1);
}
```

**Вывод**:

```
i want  to   make upper case
I Want  To   Make Upper Case
```

Пример на [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/l94xE3).

Comment: substring это не очень хорошо

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov почему? ТС прочитал что-то про `substring`, я показал решение с ним.

Comment: потому что if (" ".equals(s1.substring(i-1, i)))
        s2 = s2 + s1.substring(i, i+1).toUpperCase();

Comment: Создаем строку, сравниваем, потом создаем еще одну строку, потом еще одну в вернем регистре, потом еще одну объединяющую результат c s2. итого 4 строки. я думаю это многовато

Comment: Спасибо, работает как надо и достаточно очевидно дял меня.

Answer (score 3):

На regex сложновато будет, а с использованием `StringBuilder` достаточно тривиально:

```
private static String toUpperCaseForFirstLetter(String text) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(text);
    //выставляем первый символ заглавным, если это буква
    if (Character.isAlphabetic(text.codePointAt(0)))
        builder.setCharAt(0, Character.toUpperCase(text.charAt(0)));

    //крутимся в цикле, и меняем буквы, перед которыми пробел на заглавные
    for (int i = 1; i < text.length(); i++)
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(text.charAt(i)) && Character.isSpaceChar(text.charAt(i - 1)))
            builder.setCharAt(i, Character.toUpperCase(text.charAt(i)));

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Выглядит рабочим. Добавьте пожалуйста комментариев в код.